# How can I download, in bulk, all of the photos in a Flickr "guest pass" URL set?

Tags: flickr, download, bulk-download

A photographer friend sent me a [Flickr guest pass](http://www.flickr.com/help/guestpass/) URL for an event my family also attended.  I'm interested in downloading most (might as well be all) of the photos in the set.  However, I'm not interested in doing the pointy-clicky thing hundreds of times to get at each of the 200+ original-resolution photos.

**Is there a way – whether another web site or tool – to download, in bulk, all photos in a Flickr guest pass URL set**?

Note: This is different from other Flickr bulk download questions because I am interested in downloads via the *guest pass* access specifically.  I've come across services and tools that provide bulk-download of one's *own* photos, but not guest pass sets.

Answer (score 2):

there are couple of ways you can do that.

Using browser extension

For Firefox there is great extension called **Save images** which lets you download images from the page automatically, I think same can be found for chrome.

But my Favorite is simple application called wget. It is a command line application which can download anything from a given page, you can also set filters for download. But the only problem with this is that you have to be advance user to use it efficiently.

Comment: Please stop linking to your own site—it will be considered spam and treated accordingly.

Comment: @Alex Ok cool , I will not link it until it's 100% necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this and thus YMMV, but try using this : http://lifehacker.com/5553663/bulkr-downloads-flickr-photos-to-your-desktop

Comment: I recently contacted the developers and here's what they said: *"Thank you for writing to us. I am sorry but Bulkr does not support 'Guest Passes'. If you also use Flickr and those photos are in a Set, you can ask your friend to share the Set with you so that you can download the Set with Bulkr. Once the Set has been shared, you need to authorize Bulkr to Flickr with your Flickr account. Then, in Bulkr, click on  Flickr > User > Replace the default URL with your friend's URL > Browse. Select the desired Set on the left side and the photos will be listed to the right. Select them to download."*

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but since I was looking for an answer today I will post a solution here:

You can accomplish what you want via [FlickAndShare](http://www.flickandshare.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You might still have a chance with the URL parameter that changes albums to the old UI and by pretty much exhausting curl, wget and bash capabilities. Otherwise: unfeasible to the standard person.

Answer (score -1):

Umm, I think this may help you: http://sunkencity.org/flickrbackup/  and its sourceforge project is here http://sourceforge.net/projects/flickrbackup/

Comment: It looks like flickrbackup only allows you to access your own photos.

Answer (score -1):

A good add-on for firefox is [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) which has a really easy to use interface. You can also add your own custom filters.

Comment: Could you elaborate? How does this add-on specifically permit downloading via a Flickr guest pass? Your answer is lacking context.